# convert NOW() to d-m-Y

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to compare dates in this format : 'dd-mm-yyyy' that are actually VARCHAR in the DB.

example of dates i have :

```
26-11-2011
14-04-2009
27-02-2010
03-11-2020
04-06-2021
```

my query :

```
SELECT table
FROM database
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(expiration, '%d-%m-%Y') <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y');
```

when I run this query it returns 0 rows when I know I have dates corresponding to the condition.
(as shown above, should returns rows like 26-11-2011

Thing is, when i run the query with `>=` it returns some good results :

```
03-05-2021
05-05-2021
01-05-2021
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are DATES being held as VARCHAR? Can you change that

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` returns a string, don't use that on `now()`. Also fix your DB, use a `date` datatype.

Comment: Its a table made a long time ago by someone else @RiggsFolly
I don't want to risk changing it

Comment: Store dates (and datetimes) in MySQL's format.  Convert on output if you need some other format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing DATE types and Strings holding a date representation.

You are converting your VARCHAR date to a DATE type using STR_TO_DATE() so use CURDATE() which also returns a valid DATE type so the comparison is comparing Apples with Apples

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(expiration, '%d-%m-%Y') <= CURDATE();
```

Comment: Thanks, acutally working. I tried with NOW() and is working the same. I thought i couldn't compare a date from STR_TO_DATE in ````dd-mm-yyyy```` format with NOW() since it returns a DATETIME

Comment: The `'%d-%m-%Y'` is telling STR_TO_DATE what format the incoming Text Date is in, so it gets converted correctly to a MySQL DATE type. Once you compare a DATE with a DATE you are golden